# Buter devant quelque chose

Tags: vocabulaire

J'ai entendu [*buter sur* et *buter contre*](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/buter), mais je ne suis pas certain du sens exact de cette collocation :

> « Devant quelle horreur allons-nous encore buter ? »
>
>  — Robert Brasillach, *l'Action française*, 24 mars 1932. Critique du « Nœud de vipères » de Mauriac.

Est-ce que l'expression signifie la même chose que *buter contre* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the entry in the TLFi the meaning is figurative.

> (TlFi) **B.−** **[Le point d'arrêt est un obstacle]**
> **2.** Emploi intrans., usuel (suivi d'un compl. d'obj. indir., prép. **à, contre, dans, devant, sur**, précisant la relation à l'obstacle)
> **b)** [Le suj. désigne un animé] **Se heurter à un obstacle.**
> • Je ne prends garde qu'à tes pieds pour qu'ils ne butent pas aux pierres (Ramuz, Aimé Pache, peintre Vaudois,1911, p. 233).
> SYNT.
> • Buter contre une marche, un meuble, un mur, les pavés, une pierre, une porte close, les racines, une souche, un tronc d'arbre;
> • buter du front, du nez, du pied contre un meuble, une porte. […]
> **− Au fig.** **[Le suj. désigne une pers. ou une collectivité; le verbe est suivi d'une prép.]** **Buter contre**
> • Buter contre son impuissance, son incompétence, son incompréhension.

In this figurative context, "devant" expresses the relationship between "horreur" and the mind of the persons discovering this horror. They are going to be stopped *in front of* it, if they meet with it, and they will  have to take in the significance of what they see. The idea of stumbling  as in "Buter contre une marche, un meuble, un mur, les pavés, une pierre, une porte close, les racines, une souche, un tronc d'arbre", but figuratively, is not quite  relevant because  there is no connotation of opposition. Although the basic meaning remains, that is, there is a stoppage, no "tripping" is involved and so, no, the meaning is not exactly the same . If, for instance, you considered this other figurative meaning in the combination "buter/son impuissance", then "contre" is appropriate because it is now question of the person's struggle to overcome the powerlessness they are overtaken with, and on which they have "tripped" (figuratively).